# MATLAB histfit - get PDF from data, ksdensity?

Tags: matlab, plot, probability, histogram

I would like to get the equation of the density curve from a plot using histfit.

I see that using ksdensity function you can get a vector of points.  Is that the best way to do it?

Answer (score 9):

```
histfit(data);
```

will plot the data as a histogram and show a smooth curve of the best fit gaussian to it.

```
[mu, sigma] = normfit(data);
pd = fitdist(data,'normal');
```

will give the mean (mu) and standard deviation (sigma) of that same set of data, which are used by histfit to generate the fitted curve.

If you do `edit histfit` you can look in it and see that the height of the normal curve is found by equating the area under the normal curve and the area in the histogram, look for the code around

```
% Normalize the density to match the total area of the histogram
xd = get(hh,'Xdata');             % Gets the x-data of the bins.
rangex = max(xd(:)) - min(xd(:)); % Finds the range of this data.
binwidth = rangex/nbins;          % Finds the width of each bin.
area = n * binwidth;
y = area * pdf(pd,x);
```

for more hints on doing that part of the scaling.